# Is this query possible SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ([myExpression]);

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

i'v got a question about sql in access 2007.

it's possible to generate a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ([myExpression]);
```

in [myexpression] should be something like `date between date1 AND date2`
or even `id > 123`.

if it's possible: how?
and if not.. shit happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with VBA, where you can either create a recordset, or build or update a querydef.